# MAMP mysql starts in one user account but not another

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

When I start MAMP in one user account the Apache and MySQL servers start correctly but in another account only the Apache server starts.

The computer has a number of applications installed but nothing else. Any idea what difference I should be looking for between the two accounts?

MAMP 4.2.1 installed on a Mac running High Sierra (10.13). Hard drive securely erased and clean install of MacOS 10.13.

Comment: any logs to share ? make sure each account writes its stuff in its own writable directory, or the unique directory can be read and written by all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you have two user accounts which you want to use for Apache and MySQL server but one of them isn't able to run MySQL.

Looks like it is a user permission issue. You need to add and grant user the proper access in MySQL. Check these links:

MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html

Apache: http://ifmeister.com/mamp-file-permissions-for-a-local-development-environment/